# Configuring SPF record for mail server

Tags: server, spf

I want to configure SPF record for my website. Reason behind this is to use Google service i.e. Having your email in Google Now & all.

What I found from Google is:

```
Create a TXT record containing this text: v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

To authorize an additional mail server, add the server's IP address before just
before the ~all argument using the format ip4:address or ip6:address.
```

Please note I've still not added any SPF record till now to my server. So do I need to two separate records each for My server & Google?

So will it be something like below (ip address is my server's static ip address)?

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:1.1.1.1 ~all
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're sending email directly from your website using an on-webserver SMTP server (not using Google or any other service) then that looks correct.  You should only have a single SPF record per domain, and that record needs to include directives for all sources of email.  So your suggested record looks right, although you probably want to put the `ip4:1.1.1.1` before the `include:_spf.google.com`, since the former is cheaper to evaluate.

So you might want to make it:

```
v=spf1 ip4:1.1.1.1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```